# How to query a different registry path with wmic?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, wmic

In cmd, the wmic command queries the registry path:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products
```

But this list of programs is limited to those which were installed with MSI.

I would like to create a batch script to uninstall an app that appears in appwiz.cpl (Programs and Features), which I believe is stored in different registry paths (I believe there are more, but that's up for further digging):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

So my question is, how would one go about uninstalling apps from paths other than the one limited to MSI-installed software akin to how wmic does it using the cmd?

Comment: It should be noted that `WMIC` is _deprecated_; Microsoft recommends using PowerShell for WMI queries. See [Microsoft Learn on `WMIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic).

Comment: WMIC buys you nothing here.  Try `for /f "tokens=2* skip=2" %r in ('reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Notepad++" /v "UninstallString"') do echo %s`

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean "Don't use" it means "Not maintained, don't count on this in the future."  Microsoft uses the cr*p out of WMIC internally.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to search inside each folder you mentioned

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Look out for a value called UninstallString and run the program that is contained in the data of the value, which contains the path to the uninstaller...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a PowerShell Script like this code below :

---

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$InstalledApplications = "$Env:userprofile\desktop\InstalledApplications.txt"
if (Test-Path $InstalledApplications) {Remove-Item $InstalledApplications}
$Error_Log = "$Env:userprofile\desktop\Error_Log.txt"
function Get-InstalledApplications {
    try {
        $registry32 = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
        $applications32 = Get-ItemProperty $registry32\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
        $applications32 | Out-File -FilePath $InstalledApplications -Encoding UTF8 -Append
        $applications32 | Format-Table
        } catch {
        # Code to handle the exception
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $Timestamp = (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        $ErrorLine = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
        $ErrorDetails = "$Timestamp - Error occurred in Get-InstalledApplications function at line: $ErrorLine. Error Message: $ErrorMessage"
        Add-Content -Path $Error_Log -Value $ErrorDetails -ErrorAction 'Continue'
    }

    try {
        $registry64 = "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
        $applications64 = Get-ItemProperty $registry64\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
        $applications64 | Out-File -FilePath $InstalledApplications -Encoding UTF8 -Append
        $applications64 | Format-Table
    } catch {
        # Code to handle the exception
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $Timestamp = (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        $ErrorLine = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
        $ErrorDetails = "$Timestamp - Error occurred in Get-InstalledApplications function at line: $ErrorLine. Error Message: $ErrorMessage"
        Add-Content -Path $Error_Log -Value $ErrorDetails -ErrorAction 'Continue'
    }
}

Get-InstalledApplications
if (Test-Path $InstalledApplications) {ii $InstalledApplications}
```